Jenkins agent { dockerfile true } perpetually waiting for next executor
I'm new to Jenkins and Docker. I have a test script that I want to execute in a stage in my Jenkins pipeline, and this test script needs to be executed in an environment with npm and k6. So, I have created a custom dockerfile for this:
pipeline {
  agent { dockerfile true }
  stages {
    stage("Installations") {
      steps {
        echo "Installing node modules"
        sh "npm clean-install"
      }
    }
    stage("Test") {
      steps {
        echo "Running tests"
        sh "k6 run script.js"
      }
    }
  }
}

The problem is that using the method described in the "Using a Dockerfile" section in this article, where I include agent { dockerfile true }, causes my pipeline to get stuck "waiting for next executor".
Notes: I'm not an administrator on our Jenkins, so I can't tell what plugins have been installed or view anything in "Manage Jenkins" settings. If I use agent any instead, the pipeline doesn't get stuck waiting for an executor (although of course my script can't execute).
